# Can't access Windows 8 after Ubuntu install and after Boot-repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I know there are alot similar posts but none of them helped me. Here is my information from Boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9319037/

The story is I tried to install Ubuntu while I was on Windows 8 and my partitions weren't recognized. I found some commands here (ask ubuntu) that helped me recognize the partitions and installed successfully ubuntu from LiveUSB.

After the first restart there was directly the error from Windows 8 that winload.exe is missing or corrupted. I booted again form the LiveUSB (ubuntu) and run Boot-repair in recommended mode. After the restart I got Ubuntu, but I can't boot into windows. Because I had partition for backup windows (sdb) when i select it it shows me the error with winload.exe. When I select windows (sda1) the screen goes black and nothing happens until I press the turn off button.

I have full access to the partition of the windows and the windows files and as I was reading I saw some posts that maybe Boot-repair changed the name or something but I couldn't find step by step how to fix that. I don't have windows 8 recovery disk.

I am noob at this so be simple or directly give me some commands and I will execute them, or some program maybe. I am sick of this because I killed two days tying to repair it. I would be grateful if you help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this would be to boot into windows recovery mode [via Windows Disk ] and start`startup repair`.This will automatically install windows boot manager( Will also fix your Boot configuration data) which will also list Ubuntu OS to boot from on your next restart.

Comment: I don't have repair disk, i'm studying aboard in another country and i have no idea how legal it it to make one.

Comment: In your friends computer , follow these steps:http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive
The startup recovery won't ask you for product key.